# nginx uninstalled, localhost:8080 still showing nginx welcome page

Tags: nginx, localhost, uninstallation

I uninstalled nginx from brew using `brew uninstall nginx`, but when I go to `http://localhost:8080`, I still get the "Welcome to Nginx" message.

What I already did:

- Restarted my computer (3 times)
- Removed extra nginx folder using `rm -rf /usr/local/etc/nginx`
- Looking for nginx everywhere from root folder using `sudo find / -name "nginx"`. Nothing shows up.
- Looking for nginx .plist files in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` but there's none.

I'm on macos High Sierra.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to do this in MacOS, but in Linux, I'd try to figure out which process is listening to the port e. g. `sudo netstat -tupnl | grep 8080`

Comment: I tried using the equivalent `lsof -i :8080`, killed the processes but they come back once I restart. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok it actually solved my problem, just had to empty my browser cache after I killed the processes.. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to suggest clear browser cache. One way of doing it without affecting entire browser cache is to load Developer Tools (in Firefox and Chrome), Both browsers have 'Disable Cache' option in the Network tab when dev tools are open.

Comment: from ''lsof -i :8080" you could find PID and then check "lsof -p PID" to check its location and files

Answer (score 3):

Had this annoying problem as well, discovered it was the httpd package that also made this page appear even after nginx was uninstalled.

Though forcefully shutting down/uninstalling httpd would resolve the issue on the surface, the root issue is actually the fact that  generic start file at `usr/local/var/www/index.html`, has been hard-coded to contain the "Welcome to nginx" message and will remain that way even after nginx is uninstalled. The Apache (httpd) service also happens calls that `index.html` file upon startup which makes it appear as if it were nginx rendering that file.

Not too sure why nginx doesn't automatically empty the file upon uninstallation but just manually change/remove the contents of that file after uninstalling nginx and your problem should be fixed :)

This post also addresses a similar issue: [Brew Install Httpd: Welcome to Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964589/brew-install-httpd-welcome-to-nginx)

Answer (score 2):

use `--force` flag.

```
brew uninstall nginx nginx-common --force
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this command but it's not working either :/

Answer (score 1):

It may be a service running use the below from the command line

$ sudo launchctl list - To see the list of services running

launchctl remove  - To remove the service

Comment: I checked the running services but nothing related to nginx. Thanks Naresh. Still investigating, it's crazy. I uninstalled brew even if I knew it wouldn't be related anymore and it's still there. Don't really know what to do next. Maybe: banging my head against the keyboard ^^

Comment: Had the same issue. This service (homebrew.mxcl.httpd) was running even after nginx uninstall

sudo launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.httpd

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution as I was in the same predicament.First run

```
netstat -anv | egrep -w [.]8080.*LISTEN
```

I found out that the culprit was ***/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd***. so I terminated the processes suing.

```
sudo killall httpd
```

All was well after that, port 8080 was finally free.