# Brew Install Httpd: Welcome to Nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, homebrew

I'm trying to install the brew package httpd (apache). I'm so confused. Every time I do and navigate to http://localhost:8080 I get a big welcome screen that says "Welcome to Nginx." I don't understand.

Am I running nginx and not apache? How could that be?

I'm on macOS 10.15.6.

I'm running pretty basic commands...

```
brew install openldap libiconv
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
brew install httpd
sudo brew services start httpd
```

And then I get get this...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yia1yk9uhsootpk/Screen%20Shot%202020-09-18%20at%208.53.39%20PM.png?dl=0
"Welcome to nginx"

What don't I know? A lot probably. If I edit the httpd.conf file to listen to another port, I get the same screen.

```
╰─ brew list                                                                            
apr     gettext     jemalloc    libidn2     node        powerlevel9k
apr-util    httpd       libev       libunistring    openldap    wget
brotli      icu4c       libevent    ncurses     openssl@1.1 zsh
c-ares      jansson     libiconv    nghttp2     pcre        zsh-completions
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Update:

```
lsof -i :8080
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Brave\x20 1225 user   35u  IPv6 0xcdbe6ccead8e5deb      0t0  TCP localhost:53261->localhost:http-alt (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsof -i :8080`?

Comment: Updated question with that output. Had trouble pasting here. Nothing in particular that I saw was running. See above.

Comment: The process with pid 1225 is intercepting requests coming on port 8080. Is this a known process? If not, can you try killing it and then check if the welcome screen is still coming?

Comment: @NamanArora No it's not. That's a browser that was *connected* to port 8080. That's why it's in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state, rather than `LISTENING`.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down to "groonga." First I'm hearing of it, but apparently it's a mariadb brew dependency. I found where the "welcome to nginx" text was coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I narrowed it down to "groonga." First I'm hearing of it, but apparently it's a mariadb brew dependency. I found where the "welcome to nginx" text was coming from.

```
var/www/index.html
```

Not sure why it's hard coding that text if it will also display with apache running. Very confusing. However, it adds that file to the default apache DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue to this, discovered the fact that generic start file at `usr/local/var/www/index.html`, had been hard-coded to contain the "Welcome to nginx" when I installed nginx and
the message remained that way even I uninstalled it. The Apache (httpd) service also happens calls that `index.html` file upon startup which makes it appear as if it were nginx rendering that file.

Not too sure why nginx doesn't automatically empty the file upon uninstallation but just manually change/remove the contents of that file after uninstalling nginx and your problem should be fixed :)

Similar problem also addressed here: [nginx uninstalled, localhost:8080 still showing nginx welcome page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040372/nginx-uninstalled-localhost8080-still-showing-nginx-welcome-page/64715472#64715472)

Comment: nginx wouldn't empty a file which is potentially public facing, it doesn't know if the index file has changed to be content and you might simply be changing web servers.